# can I write my own pseudo function in CSS

Tags: html, css

Consider this:

```
.voffset1 { margin-top: 1px; }
.voffset2 { margin-top: 2px; }
.voffset3 { margin-top: 3px; }
......
.voffset100 { margin-top: 100px; }
```

Is it possible to turn this into a function in CSS or CSS3
so I don't have to manually have 100 css classes, but
just have 1 css 'function' for it?

like below:

```
.voffset:(n) {margin-top : (n)px;}
```

**if not, can we do better than writing 100 lines?**

I prefer not using scss or any variants.

Comment: SCSS is the current wheel for such situations.  If you're so inclined to revisit the invention process, best of luck.

Comment: If you'd rather not write them all out, you could use a bash/python script to generate the rules.

Comment: I don't see how so many classes could be usefull

Comment: To echo @circusdei, you could easily do this with a `SCSS` for loop.

Comment: It might be possible to use CSS selectors. But without seeing _how_ the HTML will come together, there isn't a good answer. Maybe you could use [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selectors, [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), or maybe even what folks call [quantity queries](http://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css). In the future, maybe [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables).

Comment: The real question is why on earth you feel like you need those hundred offset classes?? There's virtually no scenario at all where I can see that kind of code being sensible.

Comment: @Coleman sointley! was trying to offer a non-scss, finger-saving solution.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

```
<div style="margin-top:1px">
```

When your CSS is so obviously redundant, just use inline styles.

Or redesign your code to actually use classes properly.

Comment: Last time I checked, inline css is not suggested in bootstrap or in general.

Comment: @taesu As they say "not every suggestion that is written on a fence is for good".